# JSDOC with React Typescript

Tags: jsdoc, react-typescript

I need some clarity on the usage of JSDoc in React project built over typescript.

I've seen people using JSDoc with javascript React but not with typescript. Since the typescript intellisense is built with JSDoc, does it make sense to use this again. Also, what are the advantages and disadvantages to it?

Thanks in advance.